# JQuery div with fadein fade out based on div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which i show in a page after 800 px. The problem is that people are complaining since it blocks the view in mobile. I put a close button onclick but it keeps reappearing. How can i make close onclick event definitive?

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 800) {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 5000px;
}

.bottomMenu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='bottomMenu' id='myDiv1'>
  <button class='close' id='close' onclick='document.getElementById(&apos;myDiv1&apos;).style.display=&apos;none&apos;'>CLOSE X</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it keeps reappearing"?

Comment: and why not put the click handler for the button in jquery like you are doing with the scroll

Comment: So i close the div with the button but when i continue scrolling div appears again since most probably continues to take the command from the script to show after 800 px

Comment: It reappears because your scroll function says so, you need to code it so that when it is closed, the scroll behaviour should stop. It is going to keep fading in as long as you scroll past 800px

Comment: Thanks, that's what i'm asking for. How do i do that?

Comment: Set a flag so when you close it, the flag becomes false, and all you have to do is check for that flag in the scroll function to determine to execute or you can unbind scroll altogether on close if it is the only scroll event you have

Comment: Note that if you want to do this across page loads/sessions then you will need a semi-permanent datastore at least, such as localStorage.

Comment: I have updated your example to show the actual issue as you scroll

Comment: and i also wanted to ask also: i tried else if with y >= 1200 fadeOut but did not work! Can you explain why?

Comment: How did you code the >= 1200 fade out part?

Comment: if (y > 800) {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
  } else if (y >= 1200) {$('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
  } else {
        $('.bottomMenu').close();
    }

Comment: Did you get a js error with that? What's `$('.bottomMenu').close()`? as in what's the close function?

Comment: sorry my mistake working from draft example. i used fadeout the same even for the end else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a variable that states if the button was closed or not is the way to go!

Take a look at the following code:

```js
 let closed = false;
    function onClose(){
        closed = true;
        $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
    }

    function resetButtonVisibility(yPosition){
        if(yPosition<800){
            closed = false;
        }
    }

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (y > 800 && !closed) {
            $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
        }

        //if you want the button to appear again 
        resetButtonVisibility(y);
    });
```

```css
body {
    height: 5000px;
  }
  
  .bottomMenu {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class='bottomMenu' id='myDiv1'>
        <button class='close' id='close' onclick='onClose()'>CLOSE X</button>
    </div>
```

The main changes were creating a function that sets the `closed` variable to false, and it's called by the onClick event, present in the button. Also, I added a function which resets the behaviour when user scrolls up and down again, in case, you want the button to appear again.

Comment: Oh my God! This works so smooth.  Thnx a bunch! A question. Is there a way to realize the same without onclick event but just by detecting how far people scroll? I started something like this y > 800 fade in and y > 1200 fade out. And then again to repeat y > 1600 fade in and y > 2000 fade out but it was not working. Can you do something similar?

Comment: Sure, take a look at this example: https://codepen.io/pedro-figueiredo/pen/PowvyNG
I think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @JohnGrischam isn't this answer the same as my first solution?

Comment: @Huangism sorry you are right but for a reason that i can't even now explain did not work in my site. For sure is a problem of mine and your code is correct and your help very appreciated. I will rank you answer useful for sure for many others that will read it!

Comment: @JohnGrischam honestly you should try to debug the code you had before to see why it didn't work, this way you are learning something. You could do that now with the original issue solved, so you have the time to do it in case if it was a time sensitive thing before

Answer (score 1):

The original issue is due to your scroll function. No matter if the menu is hidden or not, you are fading it in as long as the if condition is true, so it will reappear.

Here are a couple of simple example on how you can fix this. I removed your inline click handler to jquery,

**1. use a flag to indicate the menu should be closed**

```js
// these should be inside of doc ready which means your isCLosed is not a global var

var isClosed = false;
var $bottomMenu = $('.bottomMenu');

$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();

  // only execute if it is not closed already
  if (!isClosed) {
    if (y > 800) {
      $bottomMenu.fadeIn();
    } else {
      $bottomMenu.fadeOut();
    }
  }

});

$("#close").on('click', function() {
  isClosed = true;
  $bottomMenu.fadeOut();
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 5000px;
}

.bottomMenu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='bottomMenu' id='myDiv1'>
  <button class='close' id='close'>CLOSE X</button>
</div>
```

**2. unbind scroll after closed**

You can also unbind scroll altogether if you only have the one scroll function

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (y > 800) {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
  }

});

$("#close").on('click', function() {
  $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
  $(document).off("scroll");
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 5000px;
}

.bottomMenu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='bottomMenu' id='myDiv1'>
  <button class='close' id='close'>CLOSE X</button>
</div>
```

Comment: oops, must of clicked on the wrong button thanks Rory

Comment: Please help. In your second example which i prefer to use close button is not working for me. Can you check again please?

Comment: It works perfectly in my example as you can test it by running the code

Comment: You probably missed something in your actual code implementation, you could paste your code into a http://jsfiddle.net and I can check there but the above code works as is